# Object deserialization error

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

Here is my json format :

```
{
  "groupe1": [
    {
      "nom": "tache1",
      "type": "Tache"
    },
    {
      "nom": "tache2",
      "type": "Tache"
    }
  ],...
}
```

I want to deserialize this into these classes, `Groupe` and `Item`.
My code :

```
public static class Config
{
    public const string pathSharedFile = @"Config.json";

    public static List<string> ReadGroupes()
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pathSharedFile);
        List<Groupe> Groupes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Groupe>>(sr.ReadToEnd());
        return new List<string>();
    }
}

public class Groupe
{
    public Item[] items { get; set; }
}
public class Item
{
    public string nom { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

An error is thrown when I try the cast. Can someone help me ?

Comment: Is the name `groupe1` fixed or could any number of property names be present?

Comment: It should be a unique name, after it will be group2...

Comment: This json is an object not list. If json should be list there first square bracket: [ "groupe2":{}, "groupe3":{}, ...] but with different names would be hard to deserialize in C#.  If it is suppose to be object then C# class should be class Groupa { public Item[] gorup1, public Item[] group2, ...} = dynamic object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the Groupe class and use a dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<string, Item[]> Groupes = 
          JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Item[]>>(sr.ReadToEnd());
```

As the properties are dynamic using a dictionary will allow you to access each group by key:

```
var groupContent = Groupes["groupe1"];

foreach(var item in groupContent)
   //Do whatever you want with the item
```